# AppEngine deploy cannot find Go packages

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-golang

I have an AppEngine micro service setup in a monorepo, there is shared code between services so I've refactored to unify my go modules (they're really similar). The refactor works locally, builds and runs, and Goland compiles happily. My issue is that AppEngine deploy no longer works,
receiving erorrs such as:

```
Error message: cmd/main.go:4:2: cannot find package "github.com/gin-gonic/gin" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin (from $GOROOT)
        /layers/google.go.appengine_gopath/gopath/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin (from $GOPATH)
cmd/main.go:5:2: cannot find package "mymodulename/customer/internal/mypkg" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/mymodulename/customer/internal/cauth (from $GOROOT)
        /layers/google.go.appengine_gopath/gopath/src/mymodulename/customer/internal/mypkg (from $GOPATH)
```

**Original structure**

```
    > svc1
      > cmd/main.go
      > internal
         >utils/shared.go
         >mypkg
      > go.mod
      > app.yaml
    > svc2
      > cmd/main.go
      > internal
         >utils/shared.go
         >mypkg
      > go.mod
      > app.yaml
```

**After refactor**

```
    > svc1
      > cmd/main.go
      > internal
         >mypkg
      > app.yaml
    > svc2
      > cmd/main.go
      > internal
         >mypkg
      > app.yaml
    > internal (common shared stuff)
      > utils/shared.go
    go.mod
```

Key points are utils/shared.go was moved to outside of each service directory and go.mod were unified.


What I'm unclear on is whether AppEngine builds the go binary on my local machine when i run `glcoud app deploy` or whether is bundles everything and runs it in cloud build.

1. How does AppEngine deploy work?
2. How do I get the AppEngine deploy to find my go.mod file?
3. How are the dependencies bundled? (if it's running on CloudBuild surely it doesnt have access to private repos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've reached for anyone else who has the same issue.
A few truths seem to exist, though the docs are somewhat ambiguous about it.
The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/specifying-dependencies) say:

```
Create your module's go.mod file in the same directory as your app.yaml file. App Engine searches the current directory, then successive parent directories until it finds a go.mod file.
```

But this does not seem to be true, infact, nothing seems to be copied at all above the app.yaml file.

So the solution requires:

1. Each microservice has a go.mod file of its own.
2. That go.mod file is in the same directory as the app.yaml
3. `go mod edit` is used to tell the Go compiler to look locally rather than try and fetch via the internet.
4. Vendoring is used to bundle all dependencies in the same directory as app.yaml so they're deployed to AppEngine.

#### A bit about local imports

Go appears to look for everything first in the dependency cache / paths, but then entirely on the internet.
If I created my local package using `go mod init shared`, its module name is 'shared'.
To tell Go that you want to import locally rather using the internet, invoke `go mod edit -replace=shared=../../shared/`,
you should see your go.mod gets a line like `replace shared => ../../shared`.
If you're using Goland and it still isn't compiling, try `File>Invalidate Caches/Restart...`

#### A bit about vendoring

`go mod vendor` in your go.mod folder will bundle all dependendies, including local ones so they can be deployed by AppEngine. This is also a good way to deal with private repos so you don't need to git Cloud Build access to your repo.

Answer (score 2):

To reply to your questions:

How does AppEngine deploy work?

- Your source files are uploaded to Google Cloud Storage. Cloud Build builds your app and deploys it to App Engine.

How do I get the AppEngine deploy to find my go.mod file?

- You place your module's go.mod file in the same directory as your app.yaml file.

How are the dependencies bundled?

- It is indeed running Cloud Build. App Engine cannot download your private dependencies during the build process, so you must include them with your application code upon deployment. Details are to be found in the [Using private dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/specifying-dependencies#using_private_dependencies) paragraph of the "Specifying Dependencies" documentation page.

Regarding refactoring of your file structure: the file structure needs to respect the prescriptions given in the [Structuring your files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/building-app#structuring_your_files) paragraph:

- go-app/: directory for your Go 1.11 service.

  - app.yaml: Your service's configuration settings.
  - main.go: Your application code.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how the builds work, that helps a lot for me to understand what the problem is. I've scanned all the docs and can't seem to find anything useful on including external files in the build, e.g. a firebase configuration file that might be shared between services. I'm guessing everyone just goes down the route of making util repos and setting up cloud build to have access.
Unfortunately I'm using go114 and there doesn't seem to be much new literature on the topic, I believe dependencies has greatly changed since 1.11

Comment: Regarding dependencies, apps that run in the Go 1.12+ standard runtime can use any linux/amd64-compatible package:

   import "github.com/example/mypackage"

The route of making repos for Cloud Build is not the one recommended in documentation, you are supposed to [Vendor dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/specifying-dependencies#vendoring_dependencies).

Comment: I've used vendoring in my final solution, thanks for the advice